# Remove all characters except numeric and period

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string `v1.2NDM`. I'm trying to use regex to get `1.2`.

```
my $string = "v1.2NDM";
$string =~ s/[^0-9.]//;
print $string;
```

output: `1.2NDM` but I'm trying to get `1.2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it like this with `g` or global flag:

```
$string =~ s/[^0-9.]+//g;
```

It will output `1.2` now. Also better to use `+` after character class for efficiency reasons.

Answer (score 6):

You can remove characters with the transliteration operator:

```
$string =~ y/0-9.//cd;
```

`/c` means complement - match any character not specified in the search list.
`/d` means delete characters for which no replacement is specified in the replace list (all matching characters in this case).

Comment: The reason to use tr/// aka y/// instead of s/// is that it's faster.